# What is the significance of the final episode of Ragnarok regarding the "reality" of the supernatural elements?

Tags: ragnarok

In the last episode of the Norwegian series *Ragnarok*, we see the supernatural events of the final battle of Ragnarok juxtaposed with the mundane events of Magne's high school graduation, interspersed with some flashes to a *Thor* comic book.

This might seem to lend itself to a mundane explanation in which Magne had merely imagined himself as Thor as a coping mechanism or something along those lines. However, we have seen many, many scenes in which Magne is entirely absent—for instance, scenes with Jens, Laurits, and the serpent; scenes with only the Jutul; scenes with Iman and Wotan—that make little to no sense in an interpretation in which the giants and gods are merely imaginary. For instance, when we see an enormous sea serpent spitting out a hammer in front of Laurits and Jens, with Magne entirely absent, it is unclear what this scene would mean in an interpretation in which Magne was simply imagining himself as Thor.

So what are the scenes in the last episode supposed to represent? Are they an assertion that there were no supernatural elements involved, and if so, how does that fit with the rest of the series? Are they merely showing that Ragnarok is still metaphorically occurring despite the gods having made peace with the giants? Is the show saying that the previous supernatural elements were real, but Magnus is *now* having a bit of a break from reality? Something else?

Comment: Magne can still imagine events happening to other people without himself being there,  he is not required to imagine that he is personally involved in everything.

Comment: @JK - Well, of course. After all, any fiction is ultimately based on people imagining things that did not happen to them, right? But this leads to a lot of confusion about which parts of the events of the previous seasons are meant to be "real" in the context of the show, which is not really addressed at all. For instance, did Fjor actually kill anyone? Who knows.... Did any of the people who actually got sick from the Jutul's company really exist? Who knows....

Comment: Also, while hallucinating non-existent things is a real (albeit quite uncommon, particularly if it is auditory and visual and tactile) symptom of some mental illnesses, I have always heard of hallucinations occurring from the perspective of the person hallucinating, never a hallucination from the perspective of a disembodied eye in some random place. Nor is the psychological significance of most of the hallucinations where he is not present (if that is what they are) made at *all* clear.

Comment: It's not even clear what the correct interpretation is: besides what I mentioned in the question, my first thought was that with the conflict over, he kind of magically stopped being Thor and saw it all as make-believe, which is a not-uncommon trope.